# ng-class that changes a Date to red if passed, reverts back after Page reload

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

So basically the title. I am writing a Todo WebApp with AngularJS 1.5, and Typescript 2.3.
One "Feature" I need is: if the Date of your TodoTask lies in the Past relative to today it should be red.
And it works as it should. However once I reload the page the color is back to default.
So my question would be, is there a way to let it re-evaluate after reload or to stick it somehow?
I use localStorage, btw.

I've tried ng style and ng class. So for only ng class worked. besides the reload problem.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
      <tr ng-repeat="todo in todo">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" ng-change="save()" />
          <span ng-class="{'done': todo.done}"> {{todo.title}} </span>
          <br><br>
          <span ng-class="{'older' : isPassed(todo.date)}"> {{todo.date | date: "dd-MM-yyyy"}} </span>
          <button type="button" ng-click="delete($index)" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

the CSS

```
.older {
  color: red;
}
```

The main.ts

```
$scope.isPassed = function(date) {
    return date < $scope.today;
  }
```

Comment: use that $scope.isPassed method in $onInit method, so that it will evaluated on component load

Comment: Jesus Christ! That did it, thank you very much

Comment: Glad it works, posted my comment as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using that $scope.isPassed method in $onInit method

```
$onInit(){
  $scope.isPassed = function(date) {
    return date < $scope.today;
  }
}
```